# Azure BlobStorage restapi ETag always null .Why? (xamarin or any c# project using blob storage)

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-blob-storage

I am new to Azure/blob storage etc..
I need to read a file from a blob using the rest api.
I want to use the eTag to cache it locally and then only read the file
if the etag has changed.

**If the Etag is not the correct way to check if data has changed than please advice?**

What I have noticed that I can read the file but the eTag is null all time.

What Am I doing wrong?

```
private const    string EtagKey     = "myEtag";
private readonly string xmlFilename 
= Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
"MyFile.xml");

//get etag from cache if there
public string CachedEtagVersion => Preferences.Get(EtagKey, string.Empty);

private async Task<string> GetFileFromCloud()
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CachedEtagVersion))
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("If-None-Match", CachedEtagVersion);
        }

        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://mybloburl/XmlFiles/Myfile.xml");

        string xmlFileContent;
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotModified)
        {
            xmlFileContent = ReadFromCache();
        }
        else
        {
            xmlFileContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

        //response.Headers.ETag always NULL WHY??????**
        UpdateLocalCache(response.Headers.ETag, xmlFileContent);
        return xmlFileContent;
    }
}

private void UpdateLocalCache(EntityTagHeaderValue eTag, string xmlFileContent)
{
    if (eTag == null || CachedEtagVersion == eTag.Tag) return;
    //cache the etag it on the device using xam essentials
    Preferences.Set(EtagKey, eTag.Tag);
    File.WriteAllText(xmlFilename, xmlFileContent);
}

private string ReadFromCache()
{
    if (!File.Exists(xmlFilename)) return string.Empty;
    return File.ReadAllText(xmlFilename);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this

https://www.michaelcrump.net/azure-tips-and-tricks88/

The e tag is for optimistic concurrency and not the last time a file changed.

Use Timestamp for that

Comment: Hi not sure how the timestamp should be used.where should I get the timestamp from?